# Kafka - Resetting offset for partition does not work

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am having a topic "oranges" with 10 partitions, 2 consumers within 1 consumer group. I am using Spring Kafka.

As for some reason, I need to re-read the data from time to time, I need to reset the offsets. My listener implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and in the `onPartitionsAssigned()` I simply call `callback#seekToBeginning`. This works fine as in the log I see messages from Kafka Client API (2.3.1) saying:

Resetting offset for partition `oranges-X to offset 0`. This happens for all partitions fine.

However, effectively only the last partition is reset (9) and from time to time, if I get lucky the second one (1) too. All others are not getting reset at all.

What is getting me real headaches is: if I omit partition 9 from the list of partitions to be reset, all other partitions get reset fine and everything works as expected.

The code is very simple:

```
class ... implements ConsumerSeekAware {
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
...
        callback.seekToBeginning(topicPartition.topic(), topicPartition.partition());

}
...
```

Logs:

```
19 Jun 09:56:49.442] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-9 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-8 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-1 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-0 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-3 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-2 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-5 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-4 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-7 to offset 0.
[19 Jun 09:56:49.443] [INFO] [{}] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=orange-0, groupId=avaloq.fints.acpadapter] Resetting offset for partition orange-6 to offset 0.
```

Comment: Can you share your code or some logs?

Comment: Hi @MickaelMaison, I have updated the post. WOuld you like logs after the or prior to the log statements above?

Comment: Never heard of anything like this before. If you can provide a small, concise, complete sample that exhibits this behavior, I can take a look.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, thanks for reply. I will provide an example. I have spent on this already couple of days. What I have found out is that it happens only if I have AckMode set to BATCH and `enable.auto.commit` set to `false`. If I change it to `true`, it works as expected. Looks like there was some pending offset commits? The docu of `callback#seekToBeginning` says `Queue a seekToBeginning operation to the consumer. The seek will occur after any pending offset commits. The consumer must be currently assigned the specified partition.`

Comment: Which version are you using? That javadoc needs to be fixed; in versions since 1.3 the threading was changed (thanks to KIP-62). `onPartitionsAssigned` is called on the consumer thread from the `poll()` and the seeks are now done directly rather than queueing; the seeks are still queued if you save off the callback from in `registereSeekCallback` and call the callback from outside of the `onPartitionsAssigned`.

Comment: Spring Kafka: 2.5.2.RELEASE, Kafka API: 2.5.0

Comment: I have just figured out that if I do `KafkaConsumer#commitSync` myself directly on `onPartitionsAssigned` before seeking, it works fine. That really leads me to think there is something wrong with the commits?

Comment: It makes no sense to me; there should not be any pending commits by the time `onPartitionsAssigned` is called. You can set the container property `commitLogLevel` to INFO (or higher) to get commit activity (to avoid turning on DEBUG logging for everything). Or, if you have a small, complete, example that exhibits this behavior, I can take a look at it to see what's going on.

Comment: Also, can you see if you get the same behavior if you use the newer API that takes all the assignments in a single call? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/41ea830417398d2c8517b292aac3cff42045f63a/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerSeekAware.java#L107-L116

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell,

it is very difficult to provide a complete sample. I am using ConsumerSeekAware (or ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener) and the behavior is very undetermenistic. 8 out of 10 runs work fine, the other 2 not. My assumption does not seem correct, it just changed the time how long the method processes and suddenly somehow increased the "chance" of really getting resetting the offsets. In the onPartitionsAssigned I have to do some DB calls, which makes the execution longer. Normally, when I just seek without anything else, it works fine. There is really something fishy.

Comment: I tried to instead using the onPartitionsAssigned method to create a custom consumer before I start the others and rewind from the custom consumer. I have checked the code here: https://github.com/martin-linha/kafka-consumer-seek-issue. Here the issue is the same. The offsets do not reset. But I am unsure if the problem is the same as in the onPartitionsAssigned method...

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue.

Here is my test Spring Boot application:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So62465345Application extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So62465345Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62465345Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so62465345", topics = "so62465345")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so62465345").partitions(10).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> IntStream.range(0, 9).forEach(i -> template.send("so62465345", i, null,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ":foo:" + i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        LOG.info("Seeking on assignment");
        callback.seekToBeginning(assignments.keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        LOG.info("Seeking on idle");
        callback.seekToBeginning(assignments.keySet());
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.idle-event-interval=30000
spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=2000
```

I have set a breakpoint in the `onIdleContainer` and, using `kafka-console-consumer`, I see that the offsets are not actually reset until the next `poll()`.

`Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition so62465345-1` appears when we perform the seek, but the `Resetting offset for partition so62465345-0 to offset 0` doesn't appear until we call `poll()` again (and then the offsets are actually reset).

So I do see that the seeks don't occur on the current poll, which returns 0 records, but the next poll starts from the beginning.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the heads up. Yes, I agree - it does not seem to be Spring related. Hopefully you get luckier than me, I don't seem to find a solution for the issue. Looking forward to hearing from you back.

Comment: Correction; my idle interval was too short so that seek was masking what happens with the seek on assignment; I do see that the seeks don't take affect until the next poll, though.

Comment: That is strange. In my tests, not even the next poll helps. It simply never moves the offsets ever.